# How can I set a Session using Javascript with Jquery Vector Map

Tags: javascript, session, cookies, jqvmap

**Im using a jQuery Vector Map Library with name [jqvmap](https://github.com/10bestdesign/jqvmap). Anyone knows a way to Set a Session in Javascript instead of setting a Cookie?:**

**My code:**

```
function getCountryName(code) {
    var path = JQVMap.maps["world_en"].paths[code];
    return path && path.name;
}
var fromCountryCode = getCookie(cookieName) || "";
worldMap = jQuery('#vmap').vectorMap({
    map: "world_en",
    backgroundColor: '#FFCC28',
    borderColor: '#818181',
    scaleColors: ['#222222', '#ffffff'],
    borderOpacity: 0.25,
    color: '#2F3132',
    hoverOpacity: 0.8,
    multiSelectRegion: true,
    selectedColor: '#FBB24B',
    selectedRegions: '{{$flag}}',
    //selectedRegions: [fromCountryCode],
    enableZoom: true,
    showTooltip: true,
    onRegionClick: function(e, code, name) {
        code == "AE" ||
        code == "AF" ||
        code == "AG" ||
        code == "AL" ||
        code == "AM" ||
        code == "AO" ||
        code == "AR" ||
        code == "AT" ||
        code == "AU" ||
        etc...
        code == "ZW"
        $("#message").text("Your Country: " + name);
        setCookie(cookieName, code, 600); // minutes
        window.location.replace("https://example.com/");
    }
});
```

My idea is to Set a Session in Javascript instead of setting a Cookie by replacing the following part of code:

```
setCookie(cookieName, code, 600);
```

replaced by

```
session(['name' => $code]);
```

I read SO and it seems that sessions cannot be altered from client side, but probably someone knows a workaround using AJAX.
brgds.

Comment: The *standard* way for a session, is to set a cookie on the client browser, so IMHO this question is somewhat too broad to get a clean answer.. Did You checked [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AwicscsvGLg) explanation about *session storage* ?

Comment: thank you @deblocker , my system was working with cookies but the problem resides that cookies can be accessed on the next page load according to http://php.net/set_cookie , consequently I cannot use it to provide accurate results to new customers as soon they access default homepage

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, TBH I haven't fully understand the whole workflow of Your application, but if You need to create a PHP **cookie-less session**, You will need to pass back & forth the session id by yourself. This can be done using ajax/php like below. Create two PHP pages:

set_session.php:

```
<?php 
  ini_set("session.use_cookies", 0);
  ini_set("session.use_only_cookies", 0);
  session_start();

  if(isset($_POST['code'])){
    $code = filter_var($_POST['code'], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
  }

  $_SESSION['name'] = $code;
  $_SESSION['value'] = 'https://example.com';

  header('Content-Type: application/json');
  $response = [];
  $response['sessionid'] = session_id();
  echo json_encode($response);
?>
```

get_session.php:

```
<?php 
  ini_set("session.use_cookies", 0);
  ini_set("session.use_only_cookies", 0);

  if(isset($_POST['sessionid'])){
    $sessionid = filter_var($_POST['sessionid'], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
  }

  session_id($sessionid);
  session_start();
  header('Content-Type: application/json');
  $response = [];
  $response['name'] = $_SESSION['name'];
  $response['value'] = $_SESSION['value'];
  echo json_encode($response);
?>
```

JavaScript:

```
var mySessionId = "";

function setSession (code){
   $.ajax({url: 'set_session.php'
    ,data: {code: code}
    ,type: "post"            
    ,dataType: "json"
    ,success: function (result) {
      mySessionId = result.sessionid;
    }
  });
}

function getSession (){
  $.ajax({url: 'get_session.php'
    ,data: {sessionid: mySessionId}
    ,type: "post"              
    ,dataType: "json"
    ,success: function (result) {
      // result will be: {name: AZ, value: https://example.com}
    }
  });
}
```

Fisrt, You should get a session id into `mySessionId`:

```
setSession('AZ');
```

then, You can reuse this session id later from Your html page to recall the session variables stored server-side:

```
getSession();
```

Moreover, depending from Your needs, You can also use an http header to redirect the user to the new link from directly inside the `get_session.php` page.

Hope this helps.